# Retrieve values from dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a strange setup at a client. The have a table that defines some categories. One of the fields is a view that contains the details for this category. These categories are setup dynamically hence the view column in the table. What I want to accomplish is to select these categories and get some stats from the view in question for each category.

I know that I cannot do this in a function returning a table because I need to build the query dynamically and functions cannot use `sp_executesql`

The only option seems to write this in a stored procedure, but I was hoping there might be a better approach.

```
CREATE TABLE Categories
(CategoryID int,
CategoryView varchar(255)
)
GO

CREATE VIEW Cat_Objects
AS
Select * from sys.objects
GO

CREATE VIEW Cat_Procedures
AS
Select * from sys.procedures
GO

INSERT Categories VALUES (1, 'Cat_Objects')
INSERT Categories VALUES (2, 'Cat_Procedures')
```

I want to build a dynamic query with the viewname and execute

```
Select Count(1), MIN(create_date), Max(create_date) from Cat_Objects
```

So this is my solution, but it seems very bulky.

```
DECLARE @CategoryID int,
        @View varchar(255)


Select * into #objects from Categories

DECLARE @Table TABLE (
CatID int,
ObjectCnt int,
MinCreateDate DATETIME,
MaxCreateDate DATETIME)

WHILE(0 < (Select count(1) from #objects))
BEGIN
    SET ROWCOUNT 1
    Select @CategoryID = CategoryID, @View = CategoryView from #objects
    SET ROWCOUNT 0

    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Select @objectCntOUT=COUNT(1), @minCreateDateOUT=MIN(create_date), @maxCreateDateOUT=MAX(create_date)
    FROM ' + @View

    PRINT @query 

    DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500) = N'@objectCntOUT INT OUTPUT, @minCreateDateOUT DATETIME OUTPUT, @maxCreateDateOUT DATETIME OUTPUT';  
    Declare @objectCnt int,
            @minCreateDate DATETIME,
            @maxCreateDate DATETIME

    exec sp_executesql @query, @ParmDefinition, @objectCntOUT=@objectCnt OUTPUT, @minCreateDateOUT=@minCreateDate OUTPUT, @maxCreateDateOUT=@maxCreateDate OUTPUT
    INSERT @Table VALUES(@CategoryID, @objectCnt, @minCreateDate, @maxCreateDate)
    DELETE #objects WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID
END

Select * from @Table
```

The question is: is it possible to do it better? Without while loop etc.

Comment: Stored procedure seems suitable solution for this situation. What is the question?

Comment: The question was if it is possible to do it beter, not with a while loop maybe. smarter

Comment: I got it! See my answer, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this query into this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##ResultTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##ResultTable

CREATE TABLE ##ResultTable  (
    CatID int,
    ObjectCnt int,
    MinCreateDate DATETIME,
    MaxCreateDate DATETIME
)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT  @query = @query + N'INSERT INTO ##ResultTable
SELECT  CAST(''' +CAST(CategoryID as nvarchar(100)) +''' as int),
        COUNT(1),
        MIN(create_date), 
        MAX(create_date)
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(CategoryView) + ';' +CHAR(13)
FROM Categories

EXEC sp_executesql @query

SELECT *
FROM ##ResultTable
```

If you `PRINT @query` you will get:

```
INSERT INTO ##ResultTable
SELECT  CAST('1' as int),
        COUNT(1),
        MIN(create_date), 
        MAX(create_date)
FROM [Cat_Objects];
INSERT INTO ##ResultTable
SELECT  CAST('2' as int),
        COUNT(1),
        MIN(create_date), 
        MAX(create_date)
FROM [Cat_Procedures];
```

**Update#1**

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT  @query = @query + N'UNION ALL
SELECT  CAST(''' +CAST(CategoryID as nvarchar(100)) +''' as int),
        COUNT(1),
        MIN(create_date), 
        MAX(create_date)
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(CategoryView) +CHAR(13)
FROM Categories

SELECT @query = 'INSERT INTO ##ResultTable'+CHAR(13) + STUFF(@query,1,10,'')
```

Print:

```
INSERT INTO ##ResultTable
SELECT  CAST('1' as int),
        COUNT(1),
        MIN(create_date), 
        MAX(create_date)
FROM [Cat_Objects]
UNION ALL
SELECT  CAST('2' as int),
        COUNT(1),
        MIN(create_date), 
        MAX(create_date)
FROM [Cat_Procedures]
```

**Update#2**

And one more way you can create some view and then alter it with dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SomeViewName]
AS
SELECT NULL AS D
```

And use this part:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT  @query = @query + N'UNION ALL
SELECT  CAST(''' +CAST(CategoryID as nvarchar(100)) +''' as int),
        COUNT(1),
        MIN(create_date), 
        MAX(create_date)
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(CategoryView) +CHAR(13)
FROM Categories

SELECT @query = 'ALTER VIEW [dbo].[SomeViewName] AS '+CHAR(13) + STUFF(@query,1,10,'')
```

After that you can use `[dbo].[SomeViewName]` to get data you need instead of temporary tables.

Comment: I don't get any results back on the select. `Print @query` is blank

Comment: There are no NULLs in Categories table? And you declared @query with N''?

Comment: It works on the sample that we did, but not on the actual stuff. I'm busy checking. Here is a different approach as well if you want to add it. You don't have to use a global temp then
`SELECT  @query = stuff(T.X.query('QueueViewSql').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 14, '') from
   (Select ' 
UNION ALL 
Select ' + CAST(CategoryID as nvarchar(10)) + ', COUNT(1),
        MIN(create_date), 
        MAX(create_date)
from ' + Convert(varchar(max), a.CategoryView)  QueueViewSql
   from Categories
   for xml path(''), type) T(X)`
and then `Insert #ResultTable EXEC sp_executesql @query`

Comment: AFAIK you can not `INSERT... EXEC...`. You don't need XML here. You can use UNION ALL and then remove extra with the STUFF.

Comment: I add some info to my answer.

Comment: INSERT EXEC is working. They apparently lifted the restriction in 2010. Thanks for your help.

Comment: _INSERT EXEC is working_ - yes, I was wrong, it works fine if you specify table exactly like outputted result-set.

Comment: Your View idea is also very clever.